# Typo3: CKEditor - is my yaml config loaded correctly?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, rte

Is there any way to check if the YAML configuration I added to my Typo3 configuration is loaded? And even more if it can be parsed correctly?

I've added my *custom.yaml* like this in */typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php*:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['custom'] = 'fileadmin/templates/ext/CkEditor/Custom.yaml';
```

I cannot find any information in the Typoscript Object browser. Would an error be reported to the log?

Comment: I am aware of a similar issue https://forge.typo3.org/issues/81522 maybe it is related or even the same.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi - thank you, but this is not the issue in my case. I am not loading via Resource Tag.

Comment: There is no information in the TypoScript Object Browser regarding the loaded RTE config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to check whether or not it's loaded correctly into the `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']` within `SYSTEM->CONFIGURATION` in the backend.

In case you dont see that navigation entry in the backend and assuming your installation is composer based, you may need to add `typo3/cms-lowlevel` to your `composer.json` dependencies. [Here](https://packagist.org/packages/typo3/cms-lowlevel) is the link to the composer package on packagist.

Usually it's a better idea to have a separate extension, which registers the custom preset within its `ext_localconf.php` file.

See [Exploring Global Variables](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/GlobalValues/GlobalVariables/Index.html#exploring-global-variables), [Verifying the TCA](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtendingTca/Verifying/Index.html) or [this](https://usetypo3.com/ckeditor.html) website for further information.

Comment: Thank you - could you please explain typo3/cms-lowlevel?

Comment: @Gerfried I just added a link to my answer above. https://packagist.org/packages/typo3/cms-lowlevel
The package Enables the 'Config' and 'DB Check' modules for technical analysis of the system. This includes raw database search, checking relations, counting pages and records etc.

Comment: I just saw that you tagged the question with version 8, according to https://packagist.org/packages/typo3/cms#v8.7.26 it includes the lowlevel package, so you should have that backend module already.